# Must a non-proper noun that starts a sentence be preceded with an article?

Tags: nouns, articles, syntactic-analysis

I'm doing some research in NLP, and thought you guys would be the best to ask this.

When looking at an English sentence, it is sometimes hard for a computer to distinguish between proper nouns, such as *Bill*, and common (non-proper) nouns, such as *bill* as in *He gave me a bill*.

At first I thought, 'Oh, I'll just see if it's capitalized.'  I'm wary to do this though, since I'm not sure if that pattern will hold as a rule.

Then, I noticed that every time a common noun begins a sentence (and almost always when it is used in a sentence), it is preceded by one of the articles *a*, *an*, or *the*.  Is this a rule I can count on?  Can anyone think of counterexamples?

Comment: Imperatives might throw you. Bill me next week.

Comment: So might non-count nouns like _water (is wet), furniture (is expensive), sex (is overrated)_, and plural count nouns like _guns (don't kill people), people (are funny), kids (say the darnedest things), etc.

Comment: Didn't think about these.  *sigh*

Comment: *Night* had fallen. *Days* had gone by with no sight of land. *Water* was our foreground, our background, our everything. *Daylight* always brought hope, nightfall only disappointment.

Comment: @KitFox  Bill me next week?

Comment: @Edwin An imperative example.

Comment: I feel I've been foxed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can conclude that at all. Sentences often begin with plural common nouns without an article, and they often begin with abstract common nouns without an article.

Comment: Very good points.

Answer (score 3):

Nouns don't have to be preceded by an article, but often are for discourse reasons. There are many examples of sentence-initial common nouns (the standard term, not 'non-proper noun'). Counterexamples are common, just look at this sentence (or my first sentence) for two such.

Comment: Thanks for the 'common noun' bit - middle school was a long time ago ;) edited into question

Comment: I would put forward that `Counterexamples` is in the plural, where almost no proper noun would be.

Comment: @vermiculus Um, there are uncountably many proper nouns that are plural in number.

Comment: @vermiculus Abstract nouns can also begin sentences, but function as singulars.  ("Cleanliness is next to godliness.")